# How to debug JS on Windows Phone 8.1 Cordova Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I have been trying to debug a Windows Phone 8.1 app using Cordova on Visual Studio.

I would like to debug the Javascript in the app - set break points and such in Visual Studio.

I have tried Weinre, and it gives me DOM elements, and read logs from console, but I would like to know if there is any way I can set breakpoints in the Javascript and see if a code path is executed and look at the local variables and step-in.

I have tried to search online, but couldn't really find a good way to do this - actually I couldn't find any way that was working.

If you guys were able to find a way to debug Javascripts effectively in Windows Phone 8.1 apps, please let me know :).

Answer (score 1):

Debugging Apache Cordova apps on Windows Phone targets is not yet supported in the current release but you can open up the native Windows Phone project (CordovaApp.Phone.jsproj) that's under the bld\Debug\platforms\windows folder of your Cordova project and you'll have full JS debugging support from within Visual Studio for that one.

Comment: that's interesting, please is there any documentation where I can find more info about it or please could you provide an example?

Comment: Debugging Cordova projects targeting WP8.1 is now supported in both VS 2013 CTP3.1 and VS 2015 RC. Was your Cordova project developed using VS or the Cordova CLI?

Comment: I used cordova CLI and VS 2013 update 4, is it not good for debugging js?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not yet answered: You can debug Windows Phone 8.1 apps perfectly (=breakpoints, watches, ...) using Visual Studio 2015 (e.g. the free community version).